# How to check if .tar.gz archive corrupted after download?

Tags: python-2.7, download, python-requests, archive, gzip

I use python 2.7.8 and request library to download tar.gz archives from USGS.gov site.

Data example:
http://dds.cr.usgs.gov/ltaauth//data/standard_l1t/etm/29/30/2016/LE70290302016178EDC00.tar.gz?id=48aq2ki3sr01iq18pdo8jdmi47&iid=LE70290302016178EDC00&did=252710635&ver=production

Sometimes my connection is interrupted and not all the files uncompressed properly from archive (but file is not corrupted completely). I use the following code (a part of it) to download data:

```
import requests
import traceback

def download_file(url, file_path):
    # NOTE the stream=True parameter
    r = requests.get(url, timeout=120, stream=True)
    with open(file_path, 'wb') as f:
        for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=1024): 
            if chunk:
                f.write(chunk)    
    return file_path

try:
    download_file(URL, scene_path)    
except:
    traceback.print_exc() 
    if os.path.isfile(scene_path):
        os.remove(scene_path)
        print u'<= DEL'
```

### How to check if *.tar.gz archive corrupted after download?

Comment: Are you concerned that the data you started with is corrupted, or only the data you are receiving? Do you have a SHA1 or md5sum of the file?

Comment: @Bamcclur The data on the server is fine. Just sometimes I receive corrupted files and after manual redownload they are ok. I don't have file's checksum .

Comment: In some of my requests, I see in the header of the response there is a  `content-disposition`. This variable contains is a semi-colon separated list containing a `size="value"`. It seems like if your connection gets interrupted, the size of the download will not match the size in the request. Then you can retry the download.